# SFDX scratch org definition

Tags: salesforcedx, partner-communities, scratch-org-definition-file

> Account.ChannelProgramLevelName: Could not resolve standard field's name.,Account.ChannelProgramName: Could not resolve standard field's name.,Account.IsPartner: Could not resolve standard field's name

What is the scratch org definition for `Account.IsPartner` ? Like what feature or settings I need to add for this in `scratch-def.json` file ?

Answer (score 3):

As of v48 (Spring 2020), you can enable PRM functionality by adding a scratch org like below. Documentation:

[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm#so_enableprm) and [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_communitiessettings.htm)

```
{
  "orgName": "My Company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Communities", "EnablePRM"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true,
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true
    },
    "communitiesSettings": {
        "enableNetworksEnabled": true,
        "enableEnablePRM": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get `IsPartner` and `ChannelProgramName`, you just need to turn on Communities. From the [SOAP Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_account.htm):

> [`IsPartner`] field is available if partner relationship management (partner portal) is enabled OR Communities is enabled and you have partner portal licenses.

That can be done in the scratch config.

```
{
  "orgName": "My Company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["Communities"],
  "settings": {
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true,
      "s1DesktopEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

Note however that the full Partner Relationship Management feature isn't currently configurable through SFDX or through the [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm).